# AngularJS play video from MongoDB GridFS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, video, html5-video

I have a video saved into MongoDB GridFS and a REST api which sends the chunks of the video to the client.

If I try to play the video using this HTML code, it works, but I can't move forward or backward. I can only play the video once and the replay is not possible.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/video/123456" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Client side I'm working with AngularJS. I tried using video.js and videogular.

Is there any helpful directive? Or do I have to save somehow incoming bytes? And how does it work the replay or move forward or backward? Can I solve it with Javascript?

Any help would be very appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: You can check http://www.videojs.com/ it works , why need anything else?

Comment: Because I can't replay and move forward or backward.. maybe the problem is that I don't load a file but I receive a stream of bytes..

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: the problem was the server, it didn't return the correct HTTP code and the correct byte.
To be more precise, the server must manage the Accept-Ranges header and return the HTTP code 206. This site can help you:
[Streming bytes from server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/)

Comment: Thanks for circling back with the solution. If this is an issue that other users could possibly experience, it may benefit them to add a little more detail on what specifically was wrong in the server response and how you fixed it.